# docker container only run with windows GUI

Tags: docker

i have a nodejs image **which succesfully start and create** an docker container under the GUI from windows

[image]

[image]

I try to execute the following statements to create and run the container but al of these statements ends with a container which automaticly stops after creating the container

```
docker container run --publish 3000:3000 --detach --name ats cdba263429ed
docker container run --publish 3000:3000 --detach --name ats ats
```

This is the result from the after running the above stamements:

```
λ docker container ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

There is no active container created by docker. Can you please help me to fix this.

**without --detach**
als running without --detach result in inactive container

```
λ docker container run --publish 3000:3000 --name ats ats

> capstone-react-app@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

results in the following container:

```
λ docker container ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY. /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

the image is based on the following url https://docs.docker.com/get-started/nodejs/build-images/

Comment: Is something already running on that port? You can check for docker with `docker ps`.  What do the logs or output say?

Comment: λ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

empty

Comment: In Administrator Command Prompt can you run `netstat -ab` and see if something is running on port 3000?

Comment: No application listen to that

Comment: But why is it running under the GUI but not on commandline

Comment: and is there a way to see what the GUI is executing in the background

Comment: I'm not sure what `cdba263429ed` is in your syntax. Are you just trying to run the standard `ats` image? If so, your syntax should be `docker container run --publish 3000:3000 --detach --name ats ats`

Comment: The cdba263429ed is the image id! But has the same result

Comment: The command works for other images .. what could be wrong with your image? Maybe rebuild the image? If it is a personal image it very well could be corrupt. Maybe restart your pc?

Comment: Thanks for explaining can you also explain to me what the difference is of running an image from GUI or from command line. Should this not be the same ?

Comment: In the GUI you are running an image called `ats:latest`. In the command line you are running an image by its image id `cdba263429ed `. I can't verify if they're the same thing, but you can by running `docker images`.

Comment: Can you include your image's Dockerfile?  What does it say if you don't run the container with `--detach`?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Still the image is not working. In the question i post the dockerfile and the steps of the GUI

Comment: i think your workdir is different from where you copy your files. so you would wanna try `COPY . /usr/src/app` instead of `COPY . .` i think. also you might simply have critical errors in your application in your image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Micael Davidson i updated the queston but the change does not give the right result